# Margin top only when beside a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I a situation I run into often, but my homebrew methods don't stack up to a good solution.

What I'd like to do is to have a menu beside a logo, while being responsive.

It looks like so

```
=======
 logo =
      ==============Menu=======================
===============================================
```

The way my html looks is like so

```
<div id="logo">
  <a href="#"><img src=""... /></a>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to position the menu at the bottom of the logo, but I have no idea how to do it. I can use margins, but than, once the responsiveness kicks in on mobile browsers and then the menu goes under the logo, there will be a large margin there too.

How would I deal with this?

Comment: the second `div`-s will be placed automatically below the first one. Do you have floats or smth that prevents the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) framework such as [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) it will offer you this requirement easily. Look at this example on its official documentation about [Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php#topbarEx)

Comment: I actually was, but thought the menu wouldn't serve in the situation -- I was wrong!